# Detect user is coming from which country?

Tags: ee2, module, plugin, ip

There are some channels in my table that will give different data which will vary with different countries.
I want to detect it at the very begining.I did see some free pulgins but are very complicated to use.

I dont want to store users ip.Just want to detect their country?

Can anybody help ?

Answer (score 1):

EE have native [IP 2 nation module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/ip_to_nation/)

Comment: Thanks Max. For reference, you might want to check the documentation here: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/ip_to_nation/index.html

Comment: Sadly, IP 2 Nation is parsed after almost everything on parsing order.

Comment: ok...i installed and updated..but the it does not give me country ..